# Facts and the denial of "Iff it is true that A, then it is true that it is true that A"

Tags: logic, truth, facts

The SEP article on axiomatic theories of truth [goes over a theory in which](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/#FrieTheoReviSema) "the truth iteration axiom ∀*A*(*T*[*TA*] ↔ *TA*) is inconsistent." Apparently (and this sentence is an edit), it's inconsistent with the commutativity of negation, but so I was wondering about an "it is a fact that" operator in turn, and if there could be an axiomatic theory of facts such that fact-iteration was dropped in that theory. Offhand:

- It is a fact that *S* is *P* if and only if *S* is *P.*

... so I wonder how much difference there is between "it is true that" and "it is a fact that," except that the SEP article on propositions has a [section about facts, true propositions, and states of affairs](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/#facts) with evidence of the distinction between truths and facts. **Can an axiomatic theory of truth incorporate an axiomatic theory of facts so as to lack truth-iteration but retain fact-iteration, or *vice versa*?**

Comment: Looks like it might just be a corollary of Tarski's undefinability theorem. You cannot have a transparent truth predicate without inconsistency.

Comment: @KristianBerry The SEP doesn't explain and "*the commutativity of negation*" is no explanation... So can you explain why *the truth iteration axiom ∀A(T[TA] ↔ TA) is inconsistent*?

Comment: @Speakpigeon the SEP does explain it: "However, the axioms 
∀
A
(
T
[
T
A
]
↔
T
A
)
 and 
∀
A
(
T
[
¬

A]↔¬TA) are inconsistent over weak theories of syntax, so one of them has to be given up "

Comment: @KristianBerry Ah, so, ∀A(T[TA] ↔ TA) and ∀A(T[¬A] ↔ ¬TA) actually aren't formal logic. They are expressions from some *weak theories of syntax*, whatever that means. As long as you understand the words you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the definition boss, but I'm the boss of me, definitions are arbitrary, and there can be no possible answer to a question about the difference between truth and facts without first defining truth and facts such that there can be a difference, so here are some definitions that mostly preserve the common use, following "the fact that p is the truth of < p >" but restricting it more narrowly.

A fact is a measurement result.

A truth is a relationship between measurement results, relationships, or abstract objects. (Thus all expressions of facts are truths, but very few truths express facts.)

In which case it's never a fact that S is P because whether S and P are measurements or relationships, "S is P" is a relationship. Then:

- "the snow looks white" is a fact.
- "given a hypothetical thing which returns measurement results X, the thing is snow" is a truth and not a fact (relates a relationship between a measurement and a relationship [identity] between categories)
- "if it's snow, then it looks white" is a truth and not a fact (relates a relationship between the above relationship and another measurement result).
- "snow is white" is a slightly ambiguous use of common language to imply "if it's snow, then it looks white." The "is" obviously does not imply identity.
- "It is a fact that the snow looks white" is a truth and not a fact ([this measurement result] **is a member of set** [measurement results])
- "It is a fact that if it's snow, then it looks white" is false.
- "It is a fact that it is a fact the snow looks white" is false, as are any further iterations with either truth or fact.
- "It is a truth that it is a fact that the snow looks white" is true.
- "It is a fact that it is a truth that it is a fact that the snow looks white" is false, as are any further iterations with either truth or fact.
- "It is a truth that it is a truth that it is a fact that the snow looks white" is true, as are any further iterations with truth (but not with fact).

Comment: I like how you thought to interleave the operators. I'll give other posters a chance to offer answers but so as of now, your answer is the candidate for acceptance.

Comment: Actually, I have a follow-up question that came to mind, so to avoid posting a new question without accepting an answer to a previous one...